# Pandas Dataframe - sort a list of values in each row of a column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, sorting

Here is a pandas dataframe:

```
dt          name  type                                         City                            
05-10-2021  MK    [PQRRC, MNXYZ, AYPIC, KLUYT, GFTBE, BYPAC]   NYC
05-10-2021  MK    [GFTBE, AYPIC, MNXYZ, BYPAC, KLUYT, PQRRC]   NYC
05-12-2021  MK    [KLUYT, PQRRC, BYPAC, AYPIC, GFTBE, MNXYZ]   NYC
05-12-2021  MK    [BYPAC, KLUYT, GFTBE, AYPIC, MNXYZ, PQRRC]   NYC
05-13-2021  PS    [XYDFE, QRTSL, CPQLE, VXWUT, ORSHC, LTRDX]   BAL
05-13-2021  PS    [VXWUT, ORSHC, QRTSL, XYDFE, LTRDX, CPQLE]   BAL
```

....
Please note that the list of values in column type for each column name is the same but not sorted in alphabetical order.

I want the output as below: sort the column type and find the distinct dt, name, type, City.

```
dt          name  type                                         City                            
05-10-2021  MK    [AYPIC, BYPAC, GFTBE, KLUYT, MNXYZ, PQRRC]   NYC
05-12-2021  MK    [AYPIC, BYPAC, GFTBE, KLUYT, MNXYZ, PQRRC]   NYC
05-13-2021  PS    [CPQLE, LTRDX, ORSHC, QRTSL, VXWUT, XYDFE]   BAL
```

I tried using sort_values, sorted, drop_duplicates; not working. May be I made some mistakes. Its dropping some names altogether, meaning missing some names when using drop_duplicates(). Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Are the lists guaranteed to have the same values, or does there need to be logic merging the lists together?

Comment: The sample data seems have some problem. The first 2 list are diffrerent.  2nd has 2 `AYPIC`

Comment: Do we need to check duplicate of column `type` also ?   Seems need to, right ?

Comment: For each column 'name', the list of values in the column 'type' is same, but not sorted in order. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the sample data. No need to check for duplicates in list of values in column 'type. Just sort it and select the distinct values, as shown in the sample output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort the lists in column `type` and remove the duplicates checked based on other columns, you can use [`numpy.sort()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) to sort the list, and then use [`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to check duplicates on other columns:

**Using numpy.sort() is more performance efficient than similar Python processing since numpy modules are optimized for system performance and run faster for Pandas and numpy lists/arrays.**

```
import numpy as np

# in case your column "type" is of string type, run one of the following line (depending on your string list layout):
# use this for string list layout e.g. "['GFTBE', 'AYPIC', 'MNXYZ', 'BYPAC', 'KLUYT', 'PQRRC']"
df['type'] = df['type'].str.strip("[]").str.replace("'", "").str.split(', ')   
#df['type'] = df['type'].map(eval)    # for general use to convert string like a list to a real list
#df['type'] = df['type'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')  # for use when no extra spaces and extra single quotes  


df['type'] = df['type'].map(np.sort).map(list)   # convert the sorted numpy array to Python list to avoid incorrect formatting (e.g. missing comma) in writing to CSV 
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['dt', 'name', 'City'])
```

Result:

```
print(df)

           dt name                                        type City
0  05-10-2021   MK  [AYPIC, BYPAC, GFTBE, KLUYT, MNXYZ, PQRRC]  NYC
2  05-12-2021   MK  [AYPIC, BYPAC, GFTBE, KLUYT, MNXYZ, PQRRC]  NYC
4  05-13-2021   PS  [CPQLE, LTRDX, ORSHC, QRTSL, VXWUT, XYDFE]  BAL
```

Comment: Getting ValueError: axis(=-1) out of bounds.

Comment: @Murali  Which line got the error ?  First line or second line ?   Is you list in column `type` really defined as a list or just string written like a list ?

Comment: Getting ValueError: axis(=-1) out of bounds for the first line: df['type'] = df['type'].map(np.sort)

Comment: @Murali  Add the line `df['type'] = df['type'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')`  in front of the 2 lines and try again. Thanks!

Comment: In the final output, after using your code, I see an additional double quote + an empty space in the list of values of the column 'type'. Like for example,  [" 'AYPIC'", " 'BYPAC'", " 'GFTBE'", " 'KLUYT'", " 'MNXYZ'", " 'PQRRC'"]. How to remove that?

Comment: @Murali  Let me take a look first.  As I tested the codes by defining real list rather than using strings.  There could be some weird problem if not actually a list but string.  Stay tuned.

Comment: The original sample list looks like this: ['AYPIC', 'BYPAC', 'GFTBE', 'KLUYT', 'MNXYZ', 'PQRRC'] with single quote for each value in the list. After converting into csv file(df.to_csv), this double quotes + empty space is coming. Dataframe(df)looks good.

Comment: @Murali  Use `df['type'] = df['type'].map(eval)` in place of the line `df['type'] = df['type'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',') `  and try again.

Comment: map(eval) worked to removed the quotes, but the values are coming like  ['AYPIC', 'BYPAC', '..., 'MNXYZ', 'PQRRC']; inside the list its missing some values and showing ..., in that place.

Comment: @Murali  As you are getting a real list (instead of string like a list) now, it's normal to have the values like  ['AYPIC', 'BYPAC', '..., 'MNXYZ', 'PQRRC'].   No worry, you are not missing any values, just Pandas display width is limited and so not showing the whole list if its width is wider than certain width.  You can use `df.to_dict('list')` to look into the list contents.  Should be still there. No missing values.

Comment: @Murali  If you want to have the column `type` with the original format before any processing, that is, as string of list, you can further convert the type of column `type`  as follows:  `df['type'] = df['type'].astype(str)`  Not sure whether this is what you want.  But you can test on it to see whether it fits your need.

Comment: @Murali  You mean there are missing values when writing to CSV  ?  Even though you can see all values, without missing values from the command `df.to_dict('list')` ?   There shouldn't be any missing values.  Would you mind dump the original `df` before any operation with `df.to_dict('list')` for me to investigate ?

Comment: while writing to csv (df.to_csv) , its adding a double quote + an empty space to the list of values. The list of values are also not showing in full in the csv file also. I want the full list of values(without the quotes & empty space) atleast while writing to csv.

Comment: I just gave a sample list of values for column type. Its huge data. So can't post it here. Sorry. map(eval) & sptrip & split are working the same way with displaying short form of the values. The problem is, while converting it to csv, the same short form ['AYPIC', 'BYPAC', '..., 'MNXYZ', 'PQRRC'] appears. I want the full values. Thank you.

Comment: @Murali  Would you test with converting the result back to string before writing to CSV.  That is, by `df['type'] = df['type'].astype(str)`

Comment: No it didn't work...how do I get the full list of values without quotes or spaces while writing to_csv?

Comment: @Murali  I tested writing to CSV with your sample data and applied my codes.  All are working fine without missing values.  You can also test it with the sample data here.  If it also without problem, then there maybe some inconsistent format data in your source.  For example, some strings not surrounded by a pair of single quotes.

Comment: @Murali  Try this code `df['type'] = df['type'].str.strip("[]").str.replace("'", "").str.split(', ')` in place of the `map(eval)`  code before the `map(np.sort)`   This can remove the extra spaces and also extra quotes (leaving with only one pair of quotes).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233466/discussion-between-murali-and-seabean).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```py
df["type"] = df["type"].apply(lambda x: sorted(list(x)))
```

this assume that all the values of the column 'type' are lists

Comment: Hi Amine, thanks...I tried your code, I am getting the result as: df.type.head()   0 [,  ,  ,  ,  ,]...something is going wrong. The values are missing.

Comment: df["type"] = df["type"].map(lambda x: sorted(list(x))) worked the same way as df['type'] = df['type'].map(np.sort).map(list). Thanks.